# container fails after executing command: [wget url]

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

i'm trying to download gzip file from a remote location, after download is complete the container Status changes to `Completed` then `CrashLoopBackOff`. the image below shows results of `kubectl log my-service` and `kubectl describe pod my-service` displays `CrashLoopBackOff restarting failed container.`

so i want this wget command to get executed during container initialization so i can gunzip and have the files accessed in a mounted volume. but this fails at container initialization

[image]

```html
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: docker.source.co.za/azp/my-service:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
          - wget
          - http://www.source.co.za/download/attachments/627674073/refpolicies.tar.gz
        volumeMounts:
        - name: my-service
          mountPath: /test/
      volumes:
      - name: my-service
        emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container stops after the command is executed. Kubernetes expects the container to run forever.

You can configure as below to achieve the same

```
command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
args: ["wget url && sleep infinity"]
```

sleep infinity makes the container run forever doing nothing.

Comment: thanks buddy that was really helpful. so now how do i add another command to unzip the  gzip file in the args?

Comment: So when i add sleep infinity to the command the main process doesn't run for an example in my case i'm running ```mvn clean install``` for this container and ```wget url && sleep infinity``` takes precedence

Comment: you always add `sleep infinity` as your last command to do the trick.